# postgresql group by and inner join

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, inner-join

I want a query in SQL which does `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY` at the same time. I tried the following which doesn't work:

```
SELECT customer.first_name, SUM(payment.amount)
FROM customer
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
INNER JOIN payment
ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, `GROUP BY` comes at the end of the query (just before `order by` or `having` clauses if you have some).

Then, all fields in the select which are not in an aggregation function must be in the group by clause.

so

```
SELECT customer.first_name, SUM(payment.amount)
FROM customer
INNER JOIN payment
ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY  customer.first_name;
```

But customers with same first_name will be grouped, which is probably not really what you want.

so rather

```
SELECT  customer.first_name, SUM(payment.amount)
FROM customer
INNER JOIN payment
ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY  customer.first_name, customer.customer_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I searched for! The [postgres tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/) confused me, because they say you have to put the `GROUP BY` clause right after the `FROM` or `WHERE`clause.

Comment: What if I want to add a WHERE clause in the above query, like `WHERE SUM(payment.amount) > 100`

Comment: @Criesto You should add an HAVING clause if you wanna filter on a grouped field : `HAVING SUM(payment.amount) > 100` (after the group by clause)

Comment: Isn't `GROUP BY customer.id` enough to get the expected result?

Comment: @pkaramol customer.id is not in the select clause and customer.first_name is. Depending on your DBMS, your solution would raise an error.

Answer (score 16):

You want to group by the customer_id, but get the first_name?

```
SELECT customer.first_name, SUM(payment.amount)
FROM customer
INNER JOIN payment
ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY customer.customer_id, customer.first_name;
```

You might also do the aggregation in a Derived Table, then you can get additional columns from customer:

```
SELECT customer.first_name, SumPayment
FROM customer
INNER JOIN 
 (
   SELECT customer_id,
          SUM(payment.amount) AS SumPayment
   FROM payment
   GROUP BY customer_id
 ) AS payment
ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id
```

Comment: There is an error in your inner query, `GROUP BY` should comes after `FROM` right ?

Comment: @SushinPv: Of course, fixed it. Actually Teradata's parser will not complain about wrong order of keywords as long as it starts with Select.